# the left-hand side of the assignment must be a variable

Tags: java

```
private static int setGCD()
    {
    int a, b;

    gCD(a,0) = a; //here -the left-hand side of the assignment must be a variable//
    gCD(a,b) = gCD(b,a%b); //here -the left-hand side of the assignment must be a variable//
    finalNumer = enterNumer/gCD; //here -cannot make static reference to finalNumer, enterNumer, or gCD//
    finalDenom = enterDenom/gCD;//here -cannot make static reference to finalDenom, enterDenom, gCD
  }
```

This method’s purpose is to find the Greatest Common Denominator (GCD) of a numerator and denominator entered by the user in the above programming. But I keep getting the stated errors (in the comments), which is confusing me because that was the way my teacher wrote it on the board, but it made absolutely no sense to me! Please help!

Comment: by the above programming i mean the programming not shown here

Comment: where is the method which are called in setGCD method ??

Comment: Flip this: `a = gCD(a,0);`

Comment: Your teacher is not qualified to be teaching Java if that is what they wrote.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the teacher appears to have written an _algorithm_ for calculating the GCD, not a _function_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Teacher was likely using psuedocode and not java code in class.

Comment: Your teacher gave you math. Your job is to turn it into valid code.

Comment: If this is a static method, why does it not accept parameters? And a setter at that.

Comment: Why would a teacher flip the operand order? Just for kicks? I think normally when you write an algorithm with pseudocode, you use an arrow for assignment.

Comment: Oh, now I get it.  It is legitimately as @trutheality said - you're given math to convert into Java.  You're copying it in to your code verbatim, which is (of course) not going to work out that well.

Comment: yeah we learned a new concept and then he through this on the board like it was something we should do verbatim, thanks everyone for helping me realize that it was just an interpretation of the algorithm. Really saved me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 implementations for the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

- **Iterative** *(pseudocode)*:

```js
function gcd(a, b)
    while a ≠ b
        if a > b
           a := a − b
        else
           b := b − a
    return a
```

- **Recursive** *(pseudocode)*:

```js
function gcd(a, b)
    if b = 0
       return a
    else
       return gcd(b, a mod b)
```

I believe that you want the latter, based on what you have written:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Pretty easy to turn pseudocode  into proper Java.

Comment: Did your professor/book/tutor refer to the GCD algorithm as the Euclidean algorithm at all?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns what you are looking for, then you can use its output to set gcd wherever you like:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (a != b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            a = a - b;
        }
        else
        {
            b = b - a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

See the wiki article on [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).